# Why asking about computer software is closed as off-topic?

Tags: support

[Upgrade Visual Studio 2019 to 2022 for free?](https://superuser.com/questions/1672702/upgrade-visual-studio-2019-to-2022-for-free)

this has been closed as off-topic. I just looked at the super user topics article and it clearly says "computer software".

Please reopen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the tool you are asking about is "computer software", the actual topic you are asking is "what does a company charge for this *product*".

What a company does or will charge for something isn't a problem actually *using* computer hardware or software, it is a question about purchasing things. Specifically it is asking to guess what a company *might be planning* to charge for something. What a company charges is a company problem, not a problem about that software.

It is nota question about using software, and it is also asking for opinions on what the company might do.